# Why do I get ARRAY(0x8470d6c) instead of a list from my YAML configuration?

Tags: perl, yaml

I have this YAML file:

```
name: Firas
dirs: [/bin/, /home/phiras/]
```

I am using [YAML::Syck](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/YAML::Syck) in perl to parse this file, and I have a problem with accessing dirs items. my code is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML::Syck;
use ConfigLoader;
use Data::Dumper;

my $conf = LoadFile("myconf.yml") || die("Error: Open config file \n");

print $conf->{name}, "\n";

my @dirs = $conf->{dirs};

print Dumper @dirs;
foreach(@dirs){
        print "$_\n";
}
```

the output is :

```
    Firas
    $VAR1 = [
              '/bin/',
              '/home/phiras/'
            ];
    ARRAY(0x8470d6c)
```

as you can see the loop is printing one item and it is considered as array. am I doing it in the right way?

Comment: Check out the Data Structures Cookbook (perldoc perldsc or http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the problem is that `$conf->{dirs}` is an arrayref, not an array. Try this:

```
my @dirs = @{$conf->{dirs}};
```

Comment: @Firas - If someone gives you the answer, you should click on the checkmark next to the question to accept their answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the `Dump` class method to `Data::Dumper`. You give it two anonymous arrays. The first is a list of things to dump, and the second is the list of names to give the variables instead of `$VARn`. If you precede the name with a `*`, `Dump` figures out the data type and writes it as that type instead of a reference:

```
 print Data::Dumper->Dump( [ \@dirs ], [ qw(*dirs) ] );
```

The output more accurately represents what you have since you don't have to do the mental mapping back to `@dirs`. Now it's easy to see that you have a one element array:

```
@dirs = (
          [
            '/bin/',
            '/home/phiras/'
          ]
        );
```